What's the use of "would" in this sentence?
Here, I'm asking about the use of "would" in this dialogue. Speaker A uses "would". How does "would" work?

Q: Which preposition should be used in "at" or "in" school?
A: Either "at" or "in" would be correct.


A means "If you used at, it would be correct. If you used in, that would be correct too". It's a normal conditional.

@KateBunting But there is not the sentence "if you used...",  can you explain?

The words  "If you used" are not included in the sentence because the hearer is expected to understand that that is what A means. This is a very common use of would.
